# Choosing between text, string, date, date/time (MDriven)

Tags: date, modeling, mdriven

Which one of the following is preferably used when creating an attribute containing data on when something was established:

- "String"
- "Text"
- "Date"
- "Date/Time"

?

Researching, I found that both "String" and "Date" should be able to create "(YYYY-MM-DD)" equally well.

I also found earlier posts here on SO with titles like this one: [How to convert date(string type) into date(date time ) in oracle](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11461099/how-to-convert-datestring-type-into-datedate-time-in-oracle)

Obviously there's a point I've missed here. Surely there's a benefit for using one over the other.

(I'm working in MDriven)

Many thanks.

Comment: I think, this question is not UML or MDriven issue. MDriven uses .NET Framework. You can find differences between them in C# or VB.NET easily.

Comment: Well it's MDriven, whereby UML I'm working in and that's where I'm implementing the attributes to classes. I didn't know about the VB.NET though, will use it in the future

Answer (score 2, accepted):

DateTime should be correct. You may also achieve this in MDriven by using a  [superclass](https://www.capableobjects.com/2012/03/14/information-hygiene/) that by inheritance gives all your objects a set of attributes for creation and change. This will give you "automatic" support, if you want the user to enter, then use an attribute with type "DateTime"